# split time series dataframe when value change

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'have a Dataframe, that correspond to lat/long of an object in movement.
This object go from one place to another, and I created a column that reference what place he is at every second.
I want to split that dataframe, so when the object go in one place, the leave to another, I'll have two separate dataframe.
'None' mean he is between places

My actual code :

```
    def cut_df2(df):
        df_copy = df.copy()
#check if change of place
        df_copy['changed'] = df_copy['place'].ne(df_copy['place'].shift().bfill()).astype(int)
        last = 0 
        dfs= []
        for num, line in df_copy.iterrows():
            if line.changed:
                dfs.append(df.iloc[last:num,:])
                last = num
        # Check if last line was in a place
        if line.place != 'None':
            dfs.append(df.iloc[last:,:])
            df_outs= []
        # Delete empty dataframes
        for num, dataframe in enumerate(dfs):
            if not dataframe.empty :
                if dataframe.reset_index().place.iloc[0] != 'None':
                    df_outs.append(dataframe)
        return df_outs
```

It won't work on big dataset, but work on simple examples and I've no idea why, anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this instead:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-pandas-dataframe-by-rows/

iloc can be a good way to split a dataframe
df1 = datasX.iloc[:, :72]
df2 = datasX.iloc[:, 72:]